# mysteries of : mysql_fetch_row(res)

Tags: mysql, c

If we know there are 3 results. Can we replace the while loop below:

```
res = mysql_use_result(co);
row = mysql_fetch_row(res);

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
  printf("%s \n", row[0]);
```

With the following code?:

```
row = mysql_fetch_row(res)
printf("%s \n", row[0]);

row = mysql_fetch_row(res)
printf("%s \n", row[0]);

row = mysql_fetch_row(res)
printf("%s \n", row[0]);
```

How does it know which result to fetch?

Comment: change: how does it know which **result** to fetch ? *

Comment: Did you read the [`mysql_fetch_row` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html)?

Comment: changed : if we know there are 3 **results**..

Comment: **FYI**: Your *changes* (edits) are recorded and viewable where it says [edited *timestamp* ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44853022/revisions) to the left of your username under the question.

Comment: there was 6 views. perhaps they would read and have negative feelings because i called "results".. "rows".. and it could influence the way they looked at the question.

Comment: There's no guarantee it will be three. It could be zero or a billion. Your code should never *assume*, it should be able to handle unexpected situations.

Comment: It has an internal state variable. The mystery is resolved.

Comment: @NeverKnowingHowitEnds It's okay to edit the question in any way you see fit, unless you completely change the question when it already has answers. If you're worried about *negative feelings* then I'd worry more about documenting your changes in the comments section, rather than your word choice.

Comment: well based on the current answer posted.. plus having seen the "**!= NULL**" in the code.. at least it begins to make much more sense how things must be working behind the curtains. it is adding +1 to the count behind the curtains.. and terminates when it sees the "NULL" which is probably "\0" right ?

Comment: if there were 6 people reading the question that was wrongly worded. i had used "rows" rather than "results".. even if i edit.. it may not be ON TIME to ensure they are made aware of the change. perhaps via comments it would have been "easier" to "intercept" them before they had negative thoughts mounting .

Comment: Right but not completely right, `NULL` can also be returned if an error occurs. Per the documenation - *Return Values: 
A `MYSQL_ROW` structure for the next row. `NULL` if there are no more rows to retrieve **or if an error occurred.***

Answer (score 0):

It keeps track of an index in the result data structure. When you call `fetch_row`, it will return the next row, then increase the index by 1. Once there are no more rows that can be returned, it will return null (which is what terminates the while loop in the first case).

Comment: I'd add that `NULL` can also be returned if an error occurs and that proper error handling should be used.